# Ember resolve component manually

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, resolver

I render a component in Ember JS based on some property.
Now the property changed. 
How can I re-render the component?

Here is my component structure:

```
Component
    type1  
         component.js  
         template.hbs  
    type2  
         component.js  
        template.hbs  
    component.js  
    template.hbs
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? Are you trying to switch between the two "type" components based on a property change on the parent component?

Comment: Should automatically re-render. You can view an example here: http://ember-twiddle.com/dd47192ee47c9441e16b. Check out the logs. You can add hooks for ``willClearRender`` and ``willInsertElement`` to tell you when a component is about to render.

Comment: You should provide more code though if you want help. It's hard to go on what you've given us here.